# VS Web Tests (MSTest) - How to set "One run per datasource row" when running from vstest.console

Tags: mstest, vstest, vstest.console.exe, vstest.console

I use the "One run per data source row" setting in Visual Studio:

[image: Web Test Run Settings]

As the dialog says, this is not saved.

How do I provide the setting to [`vstest.console.exe`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest)?

---

Edit: I think there used to be a *Web Tests* tab in the Test Settings Editor where I could set this. [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#VSTestSettingsWebTest), screenshot below is from [this article by John Peters](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mstest-test-settings-file-john-peters/).

My (VS 2017 Enterprise) Test Settings Editor does not show all these tabs. Only has `General`, `Deployment`, `Setup and Cleanup Scripts`, and `Additional Settings`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using the default `Local.testsettings` that comes with a VS 2017 Performance and Load Test project.

Turns out that if you hand-edit "LoadTest" at the end to "WebTest" then all the missing tabs appear. Including the `Web Test` tab which has the option I needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Local" id="f541a35f-e46f-453e-82d1-813b068f8a1c" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment enabled="false" />
  <Execution>
    <TestTypeSpecific />
    <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="TestSettingsUIType" value="LoadTest" />
  </Properties>
</TestSettings>
```